# firebase kakao login with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, kakao

trying to create kakao login on my angular app with firebase.

```
  kakaoLogin() {
    window.Kakao.Auth.loginForm({
      success: (authObj: any) => {
        this.getKakao(authObj.access_token).then(res => { })
        this.afAuth.signInWithCustomToken(authObj.access_token).then(res => {
          console.log(res);

        })
      },
      fail(err: any) {
        console.log(err);
      },
    })
  }
  async getKakaoUser(token: string): Promise<User> {
    const kakaoUser: any = await this.http.get('https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/user/me?secure_resource=true', {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });
    const user: any = {
      uid: `kakao:${kakaoUser.data.kakao_account.email}`,
      email: kakaoUser.data.kakao_account.email || "",
      displayName: kakaoUser.data.properties.nickname || "",
      photoURL: kakaoUser.data.properties.profile_image,
      provider: 'kakao',
    };
    return user;
  }
```

but it says `Invalid assertion format. 3 dot separated segments required. (auth/invalid-custom-token).`

as i've read some post on SO that `authObj.access_token` is not JWT token, so how can i convert it to JWT token?

Comment: Kakao is a new tag, you might have troubles to find someone who know this library.

Answer (score 0):

If `Kakao` doesn't return a JWT with an ID token, there's no way to securely create one from that in your client-side application code. After all, if you could do that, so could anyone else.

What you *can* do is parse the token you get (how to do that depends on what Kakao returns) and then [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run. You can then [sign in with that custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) on the client.